# Laravel Auth Issue with multi auth

Tags: laravel

I have Made Multi AUTH in Laravel for admin and user with Two Tables but  in login there is validation error if I type any password the form logging me to Dashboard  plus if i tried to access any link from Dashboard redirect me back to login ?

[LoginController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkPrW.png) `LoginController`
[Redirect If Authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or9ol.png)  `RedirectIfAuthenticated`
[Authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QCdT.png) `Authenticate`
[AUTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVopZ.png) `Auth file`
[Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW0X9.png)`Admin Route`

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question instead of images.

Comment: You can check my answer.

Comment: If you found that the answer is helpful then don't forget to accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @DMalan Same below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Login error

Look at carefully your LoginToDashboard function. You have declared guard named admins but when you check in this function you are trying to use called Admin. So, It does not match with your declared guard. So,
You can make your LoginToDashboard function like this->

```
//perform login here
public function LoginToDashboard(Request $request){
    //validation part
    $this->validate($request,[
       'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|min:8'
    ]);
    //need to match your user's credentials
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember)){
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInupt($request->only('email','remember'));
}
```

Now make your auth.php page like this->

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Now come here the page named RedirectIfAuthenticated and make changes on the handle function like this->

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard){
        case 'admin':
            if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
         }
            break;
    }


    return $next($request);
   }
  }
```

Finally come to this portion that is if the user is not authenticated then what will be the approach. You can add a function like this in your handler.php page

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }

    $guard=Arr::get($exception->guards(),0);
    switch($guard){
        case'admin':
            $login='admin/login';
            break;
        default:
            $login='login';
            break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest($login);

    }
```

I think you got your answer. Let me know about your further improvements.

Comment: Method 'App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated()' is not compatible with method 'Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated()'. , i got this error in handler.php

Comment: import this at the top : use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

Comment: Class 'App\Exceptions\Arr' not found after import Get this error plus {Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth'.} on the if statement for validation

Comment: import this as well at the top: use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Comment: Get this error plus {Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth'.} on the if statement for validation. On which page the error gives like this.

Comment: LoginController=> if(Auth::guard('Admin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password],$request->remember)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInupt($request->only('email','remember'));
    }

Comment: Firstly make sure that your guard name must be like admin not Admin.

Comment: You can do the same what I have proposed for you in the answer section.

Comment: i already copied your code but unfortunately still gave  me error =>Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth' not found if i changed Admin to admin => give me Auth guard [admin] is not defined.